# Error with Dynamic SQL statement cutting off with exec command

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, pivot

I am attempting to pivot a column with 400 or so unique values with the following code:

```
       Declare @t VARCHAR(10)
       Declare @A VARCHAR(1000)
       Declare @B VARCHAR(1000)
       set @A='SELECT Name, IRIS_ID__c'
       SET @B='('
       SELECT @A=@A+',['+Question_Concept_With_ImpactArea__c+'] as ['+Question_Concept_With_ImpactArea__c+']',@B=@B+'['+Question_Concept_With_ImpactArea__c+']'
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Question_Concept_With_ImpactArea__c 
             FROM  Company_Number_Response)  cur
       -- removing last ',' from both variables
       SET @B=SUBSTRING(@B,1,LEN(@B)-1)
       SET @A=@A+ + '    
       FROM 
          (SELECT NAME,  IRIS_ID__c, Selected, Question_Concept_With_ImpactArea__c                           
          FROM Company_Number_Response) s  PIVOT (max(Unified_Response__c) 
          FOR  Question_Concept_With_ImpactArea__c IN ' +@B+')) p ORDER BY [IRIS_ID__c];'
      exec(@A);
```

Running this code throws an error that "Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'CM_PcCOGSSup'
Incorrect Syntax near 'CM_PcCOGSSup'

When I change the last command from exec to print I can see that many of the values are being read, but the statement simply cuts off at the value in the above error. I checked the data and do not see any characters that would be causing this. Additionally, I thought the result might be too long and changed the max number for results to text to 8192.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using SQL Server 2005 or up, change your variable declarations to `varchar(max)`. It's cutting off because you've only supplied `varchar(1000)`, and string concatenation does not automatically lengthen `char` data types--they get truncated.

In SQL 2000 you can only use `varchar(8000)`. If you need longer than that you will have to get creative--a pretty difficult task.

You also have `SET @A=@A+ + '`. If that's working, it's a surprise to me, but in any case there should only be one `+` there.

And, you should not just put square brackets around columns to make them a valid `sysname` data type. You should use the `QuoteName` function:

```
SELECT @A = @A + ',' + QuoteName(Question_Concept_With_ImpactArea__c) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @Columns VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Columns = STUFF((
    SELECT DISTINCT ', ['+ Question_Concept_With_ImpactArea__c + ']'
    FROM dbo.Company_Number_Response
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')

SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT Name, IRIS_ID__c, ' + @Columns + '     
FROM 
(
    SELECT NAME, IRIS_ID__c, Selected, Question_Concept_With_ImpactArea__c                           
    FROM Company_Number_Response
) s  
PIVOT (
    max(Unified_Response__c) 
    FOR Question_Concept_With_ImpactArea__c IN (' + @Columns + ')
) p 
ORDER BY [IRIS_ID__c];'

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```